# open and write to existing fstream without overwrite/clearing in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iostream, fstream, ofstream

I have an existing txt file, I want to be able to write stuff to it (on the next line) without modifying the existing contents. What's a good way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
ofstream myfile ("ex.txt");
```

seems to clear all the existing text.

Comment: I recommend you read more about the [`open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) function, or the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file using the `ios_base::app` flag

Answer (score 2):

`ofstream myfile ("ex.txt", ios_base::app);` will open a file in append mode. Each write operation will append to the existing contents.